# XSL stylesheet: creating Hyperlink based of query item_id

Tags: xslt, hyperlink

I am new to coding. Started XSL coding from past 1 month.
I want to creat a hyperlink according to the item_id.
But my concat is not working as desired.

My requirement is that i have to get create hyperlinks based on the variable item_id
For example:
https://xyz.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_startlink=maintain&g_startdata=**194970**&g_userid=msbzzh&g_session_id=6017650`

https://xyz.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_startlink=maintain&g_startdata=**194971**&g_userid=msbzzh&g_session_id=6017650

where the variable item_id comes inbetween the link. (194970, 194971 and so on)

So here is my code:

```
<xsl:when test ="$propName ='item_id'">
<td>
<xsl:variable name="itemId" select="$occRef/@*[local-name()=$propName]" />
<a href = "{concat('https://xyz.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_startlink=maintain&g_startdata=','<xsl:value-of select="$itemId"/>','&g_userid=msbzzh&g_session_id=6017650')}" target="_blank"> <xsl:value-of select="$itemId" /></a> 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
</td>
</xsl:when>
```

and i also tried like this.. But both of them didn't work out.

```
<a href = "{concat('https://xyz.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_startlink=maintain&g_startdata=','$itemId','&g_userid=msbzzh&g_session_id=6017650')}" target="_blank"> <xsl:value-of select="$itemId" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: You forgot to escape ampersands and indeed the variable was used incorrectly. See below the correct syntax.

```
<xsl:when test="$propName='item_id'">
  <td>
    <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="$occRef/@*[local-name()=$propName]"/>
    <a href="{concat('https://xyz.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&amp;g_startlink=maintain&amp;g_startdata=', $itemId, '&amp;g_userid=msbzzh&amp;g_session_id=6017650')}" target="_blank">
      <xsl:value-of select="$itemId"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
  </td>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i already tried this.. But it didn't worked out too.

Comment: Well, this is definitely the correct syntax. Could you show what you're getting as a result of my version of XSLT? May it be that $itemId variable is not set properly? There may be an issue with XPath instead.

Comment: my xsl code works properly when i comment this <a href> line code.. when i try to execute with this line i get an error saying that: internal error occurring while applying the report stylesheet.

Comment: See my update. You can even see that <a href> is not properly highlighted in your question due to syntax errors.

Comment: I got the point of how to use the " &amp; ". This was my mistake in the code. Thank you so much for the help. It works fine now.